# Xamarin.Forms.Svg.SvgImageSource.FromSvgUri() does not work with file:// URIs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to load a SVG file stored in a temp directory evaluated by Path.GetTempPath() -- but this does not seem to work:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Svg.SvgImageSource.FromSvgUri("file:///Users/jay/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/398F23D7-B2A5-4F7C-B949-5E7E3B9AA0F1/data/Containers/Data/Application/B7EC93CF-1340-44CB-8DC5-72FDCD1349A1/tmp/tempPath/svgs/register_icon_pin.svg", 80, 80, Color.Green);
```

Is this not supported?

Comment: use `FromSVGStream` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `FromSVGStream` (as mentioned by Jason in the comments)

Sample code:

```
System.Func<Stream> stream = () => new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

return Xamarin.Forms.Svg.SvgImageSource.FromSvgStream(stream, 80, 80, Color.Green);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using this [Plugin](https://github.com/muak/SvgImageSource)

There is an [Issue](https://github.com/muak/SvgImageSource/issues/14) saying that they don't support UWP

Nevertheless it also looks like you could try and use it from your PCL project.In that case, don't forget to innit the library     `SvgImageSource.RegisterAssembly();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you load svg on UWP platform.

You could try to use `Vapolia.Xamarin.Svg.Forms`. It supports on Xamarin.Forms (Android, iOS, UWP).

```
    <svg:SvgImage Source="the svg path" x:Name="svgImage" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

Comment: No.. I'm not developing for UWP.. this is just for ios and android